# Select all from one table but remove if it exists from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I currently got a table called Group, it contains a bio and a name and an unique id number on the group.

Then i also got another table called user_groups which also has an unique id, a user_id and group_id which is the same as the unique number on the group is.

So currently im selecting all groups like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM groups WHERE 1"
```

Which results in all groups.

So I tried doing this to get all group from the group table except the groups the user got from the other table user_groups

```
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM groups 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_groups 
ON groups.id = user_groups.group_id 
WHERE user_groups.user_id != '".$_SESSION['id']."' 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM groups 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN user_groups 
ON groups.id = user_groups.group_id 
WHERE user_groups.user_id != '".$_SESSION['id']."'";
```

When I put = to, I get the groups that exists with the user_id from user_groups table but I want all groups that is not linked to an id. How do I acheive this?

[image]

[image]

So in my case user with id 15 already "has" group 1 so I dont want to show it for them.:)

Comment: `WHERE user_groups.user_id != '".$_SESSION['id']."' ` , isn't it will give you single record? or users are bind to multiple groups?

Comment: the users are bind to multiple groups, so i would like to select all groups, but not the ones the user already "has"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `NOT EXISTS` which is efficient and convenient for this style of query as it will locate just the rows in the group table where the current user is NOT a member.

```
SELECT *
FROM groups
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM user_groups
        WHERE groups.id = user_groups.group_id
            AND user_groups.user_id = $_SESSION[id]
        )
```

Note the subquery used for `NOT EXISTS` does not need to return any data through its own select clause; so `select NULL` may be used, but some prefer to use `select 1` or `select *` instead. Note too that because we are using NOT EXISTS we actually need to find the rows that the user IS a match so we use `= $_SESSION[id]` instead of `<>` or `!=`

Comment: that makes sense, I somehow need to find rows that the user is a match and take advantage of that. Great answer thanks alot!